# Getting the largest integer value from many lists

Tags: scala

I want to get the maximum integer value of a bunch of lists.

How can I do this?  Keep in mind, some of the lists maybe empty.

I tried something but I was getting:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: empty.max
```

So I just have a bunch of lists like:

```
val l1 = List.empty
val l2 = List(1,2,3)
val l3 = List(4,5,6)
val l4 = List(10)
```

I am doing this currently:

```
(l1 ++ l2 ++ l3).max
```

Comment: @GabrielePetronella I updated my question.  If the lists are empty it will throw an error.

Answer (score 4):

The max may not exist if all the lists are empty, so we can model the result as an `Option[Int]`.

Here's a simple way of doing it:

```
val max: Option[Int] = List(l1, l2, l3, l4).flatten match {
  case Nil => None
  case list => Some(list.max)
}
```

Performing an operation on a `List` if not empty is a common use case, so there's an ad-hoc combinator that you can use alternatively, [`reduceOption`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#reduceOption[A1%3E:A](op:(A1,A1)=%3EA1):Option[A1]), as suggested by Jean Logeart's answer:

If you're into one-liners, you can do:

```
val max: Option[Int] = List(l1, l2, l3, l4).flatten.reduceOption(_ max _)
```

although I would prefer the first (more verbose) solution, as I personally find it easier to read.

---

If instead you want to have a default result, you can fold over the flattened `List` starting with your default:

```
val max: Int = List(l1, l2, l3, l4).flatten.foldLeft(0)(_ max _) // 0 or any default
```

or alternatively, just prepend a 0 to your original solution

```
val max = (0 :: l1 ++ l2 ++ l3).max
```

Comment: If I am defaulting to 0, I can just add a List(0) and keep my solution right?

Comment: Yes, you can force the list to be non empty and that would work. Otherwise, you can do `List(l1, l2, l3, l4).flatten.foldLeft(0)(_ max _)`

Comment: Note: The first solution works even when you are working with types which are comparable, but not numeric (no max operator).

Answer (score 3):

If all the lists can be empty:

```
val max: Option[Int] = Seq(l1, l2, l3, l4).flatten.reduceOption(_ max _)
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much all of the other answers are using `flatten` or `flatMap` to create an intermediate list. If all of your lists are quite large, that's needless memory overhead. My solution uses iterators to avoid the extra allocation in the middle.

```
val list = List(l1, l2, l3, l4)
val max = list.iterator.flatMap(_.iterator).reduceOption(_ max _)
```

As pointed out in a comment, the `.flatMap(_.iterator)` can actually be replaced by a `flatten`. Since it's being called on an iterator, the result is another iterator, rather than a complete list.

Comment: Just `flatten` will do the same as `flatMap(_.iterator)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running into an exception where ALL of the lists are empty, then this will solve that:

```
 (0 :: l1 ++ l2 ++ l3).max
```

Assuming you just want to default to 0 if they are all empty.

Comment: This is missing the point, it's exactly the same solution the OP already tried. The issue arises when all lists are empty.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella The code I posted fixes the exception produced by code posted by the OP (as posted in the example). It's not clear that the problem is that ALL lists are empty, that's certainly not what the OP posted. Either way, I'll include a solution for that case as well.

Comment: The exception the OP posted derives from running max on an empty list (try `List.empty[Int].max`). Since the OP is already concatenating the lists in their attempt, the issue is that all lists may be empty (as confirmed in the comments to the question)

Comment: @GabrielePetronella My answer was posted before the clarification. I was relying on the posted code. Either way, I've updated the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a way you can use Options and a `try`/`catch` to find the max:

```
scala> val l = List(List.empty, List(1,2,3), List(4,5,6), List(10))
l: List[List[Int]] = List(List(), List(1, 2, 3), List(4, 5, 6), List(10))

scala> l.flatMap(x => try{ Some(x.max) } catch {case _ => None}).max
res0: Int = 10
```

In light of the comments below: don't use exceptions for control flow. I would recommend using [Gabriele Petronella's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40638797/2661491).

Comment: no need to catch an exception when you can simply check whether the list is empty before

Comment: http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/189222/are-exceptions-as-control-flow-considered-a-serious-antipattern-if-so-why

Comment: @evan058 about your edit, `flatten.max` is not my solution (rather the OP's attempt) as it doesn't take empty lists into consideration

Comment: @GabrielePetronella fixed (hopefully for good). I would delete this answer but I think it is a good example of what not to do (but I can delete it if that is more in line with community guidelines).

Comment: your call, I would say